# Grease Pencil - Convert mesh to grease pencil with color Attributes

Tags: grease-pencil, vertex-colors

I have Converted a mesh with Color Attribute (vertex color) to grease pencil.
It create solid Fill Shaders for each different Color Attribute but all are white ...

Is it possible to keep all color attribute instead to have a fully white result ?

I'm using Blender 4.0

Edit :

Anyone can tell me if :

```
1- It's a Bug

2- This feature is not implemented

3- I do it wrong
```

Thanks !